# Broadcast screen on LAN (wifi) to many clients

Tags: wireless-networking, video, ethernet, broadcast

I would like to know if the following is possible, and how to go about it if it is:

*I want to lecture using my laptop in front of 100 students, each with their own laptop. I want my screen, or part of it, to appear **live** as a window in each of their laptops.*

I am thinking that I might create a LAN with a simple wifi router, connect to it with my laptop and ask the students to do the same. I would then broadcast my screen to the viewers.

My big question is if there is a way to do this without having the required bandwidth to depend on the number of viewers.

Comment: There are plenty of screensharing/conferencing solutions available although IMO, broadcasting to a room full of laptops may be more complicated than it is worth as someone will always have an issue that slows you down.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is to use something like google hangouts with screenshare. Depending on your institution's internet bandwidth, this may not work as well though. You may be able to use VNC or teamviewer to do this as well. VNC, I know can run with just a local network, i'm not sure about teamviewer, though. [Here](https://code.google.com/p/vnc-easy-broadcast/) is a project to broadcast VNC. I have not used it, but it may be a good place to start.

Comment: I'm afraid bandwidth will be my main problem. If one needs bandwidth X in order to broadcast his screen with VNC would it not be 100*X in order to broadcast to 100 users?